# How to create a new ordinal variable according to other variables?

Tags: r, variables, conditional-statements, sequences

Hi to all the members of the community. 
This question might seems identical to another that I asked some time before, so may be could be a repetition but the request output is definitely different from the previous question.

I have the following DB:

```
ID1=rep((1:1),20)
ID2=rep((2:2),20)
ID3=rep((3:3),20)
ID<-c(ID1,ID2,ID3)
DATE1=rep("2013-1-1",10)
DATE2=rep("2013-1-2",10)
DATE=c(DATE1,DATE2)
IN<-data.frame(ID,DATE=rep(DATE,3))
```

and I would like to create a new variable that could identify how many burst (a burst is defined as a cycle of observation within each day) were recorded for each id, like this:

```
IN$BURSTTRUE<-rep(c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),3)
```

Until now I have try this solution (but unfortunately it doesn't work because it correctly identifies each burst, but not according to each id).

```
IN$BURST<-with(IN,as.numeric(interaction(IN$ID,IN$DATE,lex.order=TRUE)))
```

I suppose that the function `ave` could be useful to solve this task: I tried several combinations but none work so I report the solution more near to the request output.
As always any suggestion is greatly appreciate!

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(IN$ID, IN$DATE))` ??

Comment: @Arun I think your answer was the right one. Why did you delete?

Comment: Hi @Arun, I don't want a count of how many records. I want to identify for each ID how many burst, like in the output provided.

Comment: @stefano, I've undeleted my answer. Please check if that's what you require.

Comment: +1 for a reproducible example showing desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create your data.frame `IN` with the parameter `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as follows:

```
IN <- data.frame(ID,DATE=rep(DATE,3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then using `ave`:

```
IN <- within(IN, { bla <- ave(DATE, ID, FUN=function(x) as.numeric(factor(x)))})
```

---

If you want `aggregation` (like simon's answer) that can be accomplished using `ave` as well by:

```
unique(within(IN, { bla <- ave(DATE, list(ID,DATE), FUN=length)}))
```

Alternatively, using `table` as shown under comments:

```
as.data.frame(table(IN$ID, IN$DATE))
```

Comment: Once again, "ave" accomplish the task. Now I understand that ave could weight different factors at one time!!!Thank you @Arun, definitely "ave" is a great function!!!

Comment: `ave` is one of the most underestimated functions IMHO. It's awesome! Thanks to @AnandaMahto, the God of base functions aggregate, ave and reshape.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `ddply` from `plyr` would be one simple way to get an aggregation of what you want:

```
require(plyr)
ddply( IN , .(DATE,ID) , nrow )
#     DATE ID V1
#1 2013-1-1  1 10
#2 2013-1-1  2 10
#3 2013-1-1  3 10
#4 2013-1-2  1 10
#5 2013-1-2  2 10
#6 2013-1-2  3 10
```

@Arun's suggestion of the (correct) way to use `ddply` for this task:

```
ddply(IN, .(ID) , mutate, bla = as.numeric(factor(DATE)))
```

Comment: Hi @Simon0101, that's a good suggestion but the output is quite far from my need. I slightly modified your suggestion, like this:"ddply( IN , .(ID,DATE) , interaction)", but now it is necessary to put all the new variables in just one column...any idea?

Comment: @stefano yes, I think I misunderstood what you wanted. Arun had a solution but he deleted it for now (I guess he is working on making it more awesome! :-) )

Comment: Uao, @Arun is a magician with R. However once again thank you Simon for your help!